# PHP file never called from jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have the following script in a HTML file that is called when the document is loaded:

```
 <script>
      $(document).ready(function(){
                setInterval(function() {
                   $.get('check_session.php', function(data) {
                    alert('Load was performed.');
                });
            }, 5000);
       });
     </script>
```

The alert message will be called on the interval, but the PHP is not actually called because nothing is echoed.

PHP file: check_session.php

```
 <?php  
     //check_session.php  
     session_start();  
    echo '<script language="javascript">';
    echo 'alert("successful")';
    echo '</script>';

    echo $_SESSION['user_token'];

     if(isset($_SESSION['user_token']))  
     {  
          echo '0';     //session not expired       
     }  
     else  
     {  
          echo '1';     //session expired  
     }  
     ?>
```

Essentially, I am trying to call the PHP file, check_session.php, on a five second interval. This is one of my first times implementing jQuery, and after much research, I am still lost.

Any suggestions as to why the php file is not called are appreciated.

---UPDATE:

From Network tab:

[image: The PHP file is called]

Comment: What errors do you get in the console? Does the network tab of the developer tools show the PHP file being called?

Comment: I would suggest opening the Developer Tools for your browser, choose the "Network" tab, and having a look at the response for "check_session.php". The result of your echo statements will be there.

Comment: @j08691 No errors in the console, and the network tab shows that PHP file being call.

Comment: @kkaosninja The network tab shows that PHP file being call. What do you mean "response" for the PHP file?

Comment: @SamSmith Every HTTP call consists of a request and a response, which you should be able to see in your network tab for each HTTP call. All I am asking you to do is look at the contents of the response that the server sent, for your request to ```check_session.php```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check `data` parameter

```
 <script>
      $(document).ready(function(){
                setInterval(function() {
                   $.get('check_session.php', function(data) {
                    alert('Load was performed.');
                    console.log('data: '+data)
                });
            }, 5000);
       });
</script>
```

Comment: The data parameter shows the echoed variables from the PHP file.

Answer (score 0):

the problem might be here: $.get needs URL and other optional params. you are simply giving filename. I think you should add appropriate path also. try it !!